# I am fake in definition

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix is playful
>   My infix is a position
>   My postfix is rocky
>   I am fake in definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> an **impostor**

"My prefix is playful"

> an **imp** is playful

"My infix is a position"

> one's position, particularly in the military, might be called one's **post**

"My postfix is rocky"

> a rocky **tor**

"I am fake in definition"

> An **impostor** is fake, naturally!